# Using Linq for grouping

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, group-by

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<EmployeeLocalRegister> lclEmployees = new List<EmployeeLocalRegister>() { 
            new EmployeeLocalRegister(){Name = "A", Phone= "A1"}, 
            new EmployeeLocalRegister(){Name = "B", Phone= "B1"},
            new EmployeeLocalRegister(){Name = "A", Phone= "A2"}, 
            new EmployeeLocalRegister(){Name = "B", Phone= "B2"},
            new EmployeeLocalRegister(){Name = "B", Phone= "B3"},
            new EmployeeLocalRegister(){Name = "C", Phone= "C1"}};

        List<EmployeeTelDir> telDir = new List<EmployeeTelDir>();

        var queryEmployeeLocalRegisterByName =
        from empl in lclEmployees
        group empl by empl.Name;

        foreach (var employeeGroup in queryEmployeeLocalRegisterByName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(employeeGroup.Key);
            List<string> phone = new List<string>();
            foreach (EmployeeLocalRegister employee in employeeGroup)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("    {0}", employee.Phone);
                phone.Add(employee.Phone);
            }

            telDir.Add(new EmployeeTelDir() { Name = employeeGroup.Key, Phone = phone });
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class EmployeeLocalRegister
{
    public string Name;
    public string Phone;
}

public class EmployeeTelDir
{
    public string Name;
    public List<string> Phone;
}
```

}

I am using above code to convert a `List<EmployeeLocalRegister>` to `List<EmployeeTelDir>`. Is this the only optimized way?

Can I write simpler code for the back and forth conversion from `List<EmployeeLocalRegister>` to `List<EmployeeTelDir>` and vice-versa using Linq query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need `Console.WriteLine(...)` your code can be summarized with LINQ :

```
List<EmployeeTelDir> telDir = (from empl in lclEmployees
                               group empl by empl.Name into employeeGroup
                               select new EmployeeTelDir
                               {
                                   Name = employeeGroup.Key,
                                   Phone = (from employee in employeeGroup
                                           select employee.Phone).ToList()  // The ToList() is the Holy Grail of the LINQ queries
                               }).ToList();
```

For the inverted operation:

```
List<EmployeeLocalRegister> inverse = (from employeeTelDir in telDir
                                       from phone in employeeTelDir.Phone  // Doing 2 from ... in ... successively corresponds to the SelectMany() LINQ method
                                       select new EmployeeLocalRegister
                                       {
                                           Name = employeeTelDir.Name,
                                           Phone = phone
                                       }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The lambda way:

```
var telDir = lclEmployees.GroupBy(e => e.Name, 
                                  (n, p) => new EmployeeTelDir 
                                            { 
                                              Name = n, 
                                              Phone = p.Select(k => k.Phone).ToList() 
                                            }).ToList();
```